# view images in the phone gallery

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, imageview, android-drawable

when I save images, I want image to appear in the gallery, and not only inside the internal storage like apps wallpaper , facebook messenger

my code , On Click Button

```
holder.img_download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Wallpapers");
                if(!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }

                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)holder.img_photo.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                saveImage(bitmap,dir);

            }


        });
```

funcation saveImage

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap,File dir) {


        Random r = new Random();
        String fname = "Image_" + r.nextInt(1000000) + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(dir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Toast toasty = Toasty.success(context,"Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toasty.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toasty.show();
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + dir)));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I dont have any problem saving pictures but I want to show up in the gallery like image applications

Comment: what do you mean by the gallery, do you mean inside camera default directory?

Comment: images don't appear in the Gallery

Answer (score 1):

Try this to add image in gallery:

```
public void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    contentValues.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**instead of**   `File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Wallpapers");`

**use**

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
```

Comment: it works, but there is a folder problem that only appears if you delete any other file from the internal memory, the memory is not full

Comment: the problem has been resolved but the folder appears only if you delete any image and the memory is also empty